# Rails migrating Bootstrap from 3 to 4. File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap/normalize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

So I'm trying to update this app from Bootstrap 3 to 4 and getting the following message:

> File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap/normalize

Gemfile:

```
ruby '2.5.1'

gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.3'
gem 'dotenv-rails'
gem 'dropzonejs-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'kramdown'
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6', '>=1.6.7'
gem 'oauth2'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.21'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
gem 'rake', '~> 12.3.1'
gem 'redis'
gem 'rollbar'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'verbalize'
gem 'whenever'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
```

Application.js

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require rails-validator
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Application.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "imports/bootstrap_theme";
@import "imports/bootstrap_modules";
@import 'imports/variables';
```

Gemfile.lock

```
bootstrap (4.1.3)
  autoprefixer-rails (>= 6.0.3)
  popper_js (>= 1.12.9, < 2)
  sass (>= 3.5.2)
bootstrap-sass (3.3.7)
  autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.2.1)
  sass (>= 3.3.4)
```

Application.html.erb originally had the following:

```
<head>    
<!--Bootstrap Meta Tags-->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!--Font Awesome CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" >
<!--Bootstrap CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Icons -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons/dist/feather.min.js"></script>
<script>
  feather.replace()
</script>


<%= yield %>

<!-- Bootstrap JS-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

I stripped out the above from the application.html.erb file as I was moving everything to the bootstrap 4 gem.

I noticed that bootstrap-sass is still in the Gemfile.lock but cannot for the life of me figure out why it's there/uninstall it.

If I remove the imports group in Application.scss I end up with

> File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.

With the following highlight:  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>

Updated my Application.scss file to look like:

```
@import "imports/bootstrap_theme";
@import "imports/bootstrap_modules";
@import 'imports/variables';
@import "bootstrap";
```

This now results in:

> $color: 'theme-color("primary")' is not a color for `darken'

Am I missing something in my files?

Comment: Bit of a guess but your bootstrap variables in `Application.scss` need to be declared before `@import "bootstrap";` as per the guide here -> https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/bootstrap/4.0.0

Comment: Updated my question. This causes a different issue.

Comment: I would track down bootstrap-sass as that is probably causing the issue. I created a new app with your Gemfile and it works fine (without the "imports/*" files as I don't have them). Your original error  with 'bootstrap-sprockets' points to the bootstrap-sass gem. I had no bootstrap-sass gem in the new app with your Gemfile. I couldn't load rails-validator (might be a yarn package). It might be the source of bootstrap-sass

Answer (score 0):

You probably have reference to `bootstrap/normalize` that has been replaced with `bootstrap/reboot` on your `imports/bootstrap_modules` or other files. Bootstrap has changed the modules, so you have to make changes to your files.

Also, take into consideration that you don't have to import `imports/bootstrap_modules` if you are importing everything with `@import "bootstrap";`

Also see [this gem folder](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/tree/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap) for available imports.

Please, Provide related information such as your imported files if you want more specific answers